# What's the difference between Terraform's kubernetes_config_map and kubernetes_config_map_v1 and kubernetes_config_map_v1_data?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I'm not clear what the difference is between `kubernetes_config_map,` kubernetes_config_map_v1`and`kubernetes_config_map_v1_data`?

e.g. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/config_map

Any suggestions?

Comment: The first 2 is the same, last one manages data in an existing cm instead of creating new.

Answer (score 4):

The `v1` suffix was recently introduced in the Kubernetes provider (definitely after the `alpha` provider merge in version 2.4.0) to designate the usage of the Go package for the `v1` of the Kubernetes API. You can also view resources with the `v2` suffix for `v2` of the API. No suffix generally means an alpha or beta version of the API e.g. `v1beta1`. For example, we see that in the [resourceKubernetesPodDisruptionBudget](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/blob/main/kubernetes/resource_kubernetes_pod_disruption_budget.go), the no suffix designates the usage of `v1beta1`, and in the [v1 suffix](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/blob/main/kubernetes/resource_kubernetes_pod_disruption_budget_v1.go), the package is the `v1` API.

As for the difference between `_data` and no `_data`, the difference is that the `_data` manages data within a config map (Update operation) without an import (in fact import is not even supported), and does not enable Create or Destroy operations.